# LDAP user attribute request returns unusual results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ldap

I'm struggling to return user details from AD using LDAP, after i have authenticated that the user exists.
I am using a simple auth method as follows:

```
Function AuthenticateUser(path As String, user As String, pass As String) As Boolean
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
    Try
        Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de)
        Dim result As SearchResult = ds.FindOne()

        If result Is Nothing Then Return False


'>>DEBUG OUTPUTS ONLY:
        displayName.Text = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties.Item("distinguishedName").Value
        displayName.Text += result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("name").Value


        Return True
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

the problem is that "distinguishedName" returns "DC=our-domain,DC=co,DC=uk"
and "name" returns just "our-domain", not the name of the user that has just been auth'ed

Note: the displayName.text outputs are purely for debug purposes

I have tried various combos of requests but nothing seems to return USER details.

ETA: to the security police: this is all within a https connection, I'm not sending passwords about in plain text!

Comment: Something to do with "FindOne" instead of "FindAll"?

Comment: well, maybe, but i only want to find one.. the user that i have authenticated?!

Comment: What is your `path` parameter?

Comment: path is the domain to log into (we have multiple AD servers / domains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Dim de As New DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
2. Try
3.    Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de)
4.    Dim result As SearchResult = ds.FindOne()
```

Line 1 is basically creating a `DirectoryEntry` element, that refers to the object at `path`. The only purpose that the `username` and `password` parameters serve is to [*authorise*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed.aspx) access to whatever entity `path` refers to.

As you currently have things, you're binding to the domain, not to the user (but you're *authorised* to connect to the domain as that user).

You then, in line 3, create a [`DirectorySearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx). But the constructor you're using just says to root the search at `de` (which as we've established, is just the domain). You've not done anything yet to search for that particular user within the domain - they could be connecting to perform almost any kind of search imaginable.

What you might want to do is look at the overload of DirectorySearcher that [accepts a filter parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k4hcz9f.aspx) - and provide a filter parameter that restricts the search to just the user. I don't know what form your `user` parameter is in - if it is, say, in the form of a user principal name (`user@domain`), you might try specifying a filter of:

```
Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(de,"(userPrincipalName=" + user + ")")
```

If you have just a username, you'd want to search against `sAMAccountName`. If you have an older style domain name (`domain\user`), then usually you want to split that on `\`, discard the domain name, and still search on `sAMAccountName`.

Some (but not too much!) help on constructing the filter parameters is found in the [`Filter` property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.filter.aspx).

Comment: Yes i thought it may be something like that - as it was only returning very limited domain information. 

I have added ,"(sAMAccountName=" + user + ")" to the DirectorySearcher, now now all is good!!

Thankyou! very much!!

Comment: however i may have spoken too soon. it seems that the only attribute that i can retrieve is "name"

Comment: @DarkcatStudios - have you tried adding more properties into `PropertiesToLoad` and/or switching to the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8b03h0) that accepts these?